# Fourier Transform of $\frac{sin^2(3\pi C t) }{ 3 \pi^2 C t^2 }$?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

C is a positive constant. How would you calculate the Fourier Transform of $\frac{sin^2(3\pi C t) }{ 3 \pi^2 C t^2 }$? As it is not easy to calculate the Fourier integral $ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{sin^2(3\pi C t) }{ 3 \pi^2 C t^2 } \cdot e^{-j 2 \pi f t} dt $ or look up in a [Fourier table](https://qph.ec.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-1e2fe4aa4f7cba67d2695429151a0cc1).

$\operatorname{sinc}(x) = \frac{\sin(\pi x)}{\pi x}~.$

$\frac{sin^2(3\pi C t) }{ 3 \pi^2 C t^2 } = 3C sinc(3Ct)^2$

By using the signal processing definition of the Fourier transform, it should be something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGjkp.png) according the WolframAlpha.

Comment: We can write $\frac{\sin^2(3\pi Ct)}{3\pi^2Ct^2}$=$3C\left(\frac{\sin(3\pi Ct)}{3\pi Ct}\right)^2$=$3C sinc(3\pi Ct)^2$. Now we know fourier transform of sinc function. The fourier transform of product of sinc function will be convolution of fourier transform of sinc functions (which is rect function).

Comment: @ShahidMShah In signal processing $\operatorname{sinc}(x) = \frac{\sin(\pi x)}{\pi x}~.$ So probably you mean $3C sinc(3Ct)^2$? The Fourier transform of a sinc is a rect, but wouldn't multiplying two sinc functions in time domain, mean convolving two rects in frequency domain?

Comment: I exactly meant that, the fourier transform of the required function is convolution of similar rect functions in frequency domains.